# error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, shared-libraries, libpng

The problem is that I'm trying to use nodejs for building some css files from scss. On the local computer everything is ok.

When I run `npm run production` it shows me the error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/images/promo.jpg
Module build failed: Error: Command failed: /var/www/vhosts/site.ru/shared/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg
/var/www/vhosts/site.ru/shared/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg: error while loading 
shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or 
directory
```

But when I run the same command from another directory(For example: `/var/www/vhosts/site2.ru/`) everything is ok(script works with jpg files too).

If I run `ldconfig -p | grep libpng` I see the next:

```
 libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
 libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

So, my Libng12 is working correctly, why does the system needs in libpng16?
And what should I try do in this situation?

My system is Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find the solution:
`apt-get install libpng16-dev`
so, I just installed the required library.

Comment: For Amazon AMI & CentOS use https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/libpng16.html